# shell to print modification date of all directories name match pattern

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash

I want to write a shell program which will go through all folders whose names match a pattern like this:

```
sudo sh  shell.sh   pub
```

When run, the script will look for all folders whose name contains `pub` and print its modification date.
I wish to have code which will print results like in this image:
[image]
I have this code but it is not giving me the result I expect.

```
echo  'the folder '$1' was modified at ';
 find  -type d -name 'kam*'  -exec stat -c '%y %n' '{}' \;
```

I must go through every folder and output text `echo 'the file '$1' was modified at ';` and print the date like in the image.

I would like a result like this:

```
netcom@hotspot:~$ bash script.sh testRegex Pub
the folder testRegex was modified on may 15 01:19
 the folder Public was modified on may 19 01:19 
  the folder Pubos was modified on may 19 01:19
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `find` itself to print the whole thing:

```
for pattern
do
    find . -type d -name "*$pattern*" -printf 'The folder %P was modified on %t\n'
done
```

`for pattern; do ... done` loops over all the arguments, with the `pattern` variable set to each argument in turn.

With `find`, `%P` and `%t` give the path to the file and modification time in `-printf`.

Comment: +1 – `%Tb %Td %TH:%TM` (e.g. `May 15 01:19`) instead of `%t` gives a format like OP requested.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `bash` with the `globstar` option enabled as in the following script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
for i
  do for k in **/"$i"*/
    do stat -c "the folder %n was modified on %y" "$k"
  done
done
```

Save it as `script`, make it executable with `chmod +x script` and call it as you wanted it:

```bsh
bash /path/to/script testRegex Pub
```

Note that this will search for e.g. `Pub*`, if you actually want to match `*Pub*`, change `**/"$i"*/` to `**/*"$i"*/`. If you want to shorten the timestamp, try adding `| sed 's/:[^:]*$//'` to the end of the `do stat` line. You should also try `%N` instead of `%n`, especially when it comes to directory names with spaces this format is preferable.

If you want more fine-grained control over the date format you can use `date`, substitute the `do stat` line with the following:

```bsh
do date -d@$(stat -c%Y "$k") +"the folder $k was modified on %b %d %R"
```

You can then use the usual `date` format sequences explained in `man date`, this one here prints e.g. `May 15 01:19` as you requested.

Last but not least, to pretty-print the output of any of the above you can insert a tab after the directory name and use `column` as follows:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
for i
  do for k in **/"$i"*/
    do date -d@$(stat -c%Y "$k") +"the folder $k%twas modified on %b %d %R"
  done
done | column -ts$'\t'
```

#### Example run

```bsh
$ tree
.
├── 1
│   └── 1
│       └── 1
├── 1something
└── 2
    └── 1
$ bash -O globstar -c 'for i; do for k in **/"$i"*/; do stat -c "the folder %n was modified on %y" "$k"; done; done' _ 1
the folder 1/ was modified on 2018-06-07 09:45:28.098693507 +0200
the folder 1/1/ was modified on 2018-06-07 09:45:28.098693507 +0200
the folder 1/1/1/ was modified on 2018-06-07 09:45:28.098693507 +0200
the folder 1something/ was modified on 2018-06-07 09:55:36.066531665 +0200
the folder 2/1/ was modified on 2018-06-07 09:45:28.098693507 +0200
$ bash -O globstar -c 'for i; do for k in **/"$i"*/; do stat -c "the folder %n was modified on %y" "$k" | sed 's/:[^:]*$//'; done; done' _ 1
the folder 1/ was modified on 2018-06-07 09:45
the folder 1/1/ was modified on 2018-06-07 09:45
the folder 1/1/1/ was modified on 2018-06-07 09:45
the folder 1something/ was modified on 2018-06-07 09:55
the folder 2/1/ was modified on 2018-06-07 09:45
$ bash -O globstar -c 'for i; do for k in **/"$i"*/; do date -d@$(stat -c%Y "$k") +"the folder $k was modified on %b %d %R"; done; done' _ 1
the folder 1/ was modified on Jun 07 09:45
the folder 1/1/ was modified on Jun 07 09:45
the folder 1/1/1/ was modified on Jun 07 09:45
the folder 1something/ was modified on Jun 07 09:55
the folder 2/1/ was modified on Jun 07 09:45
$ bash -O globstar -c 'for i; do for k in **/"$i"*/; do date -d@$(stat -c%Y "$k") +"the folder $k%twas modified on %b %d %R"; done; done | column -ts'"$'\t'" _ 1
the folder 1/           was modified on Jun 07 09:45
the folder 1/1/         was modified on Jun 07 09:45
the folder 1/1/1/       was modified on Jun 07 09:45
the folder 1something/  was modified on Jun 07 09:55
the folder 2/1/         was modified on Jun 07 09:45
```

Answer (score 4):

The `find` command can do what you need with one line
You may have a look at the `printf` action in `find`
See`man find` for parameters details of printf

**Example**

```
find /PATH/TO/SCAN -type d -iname '*pub*' -printf "%p %TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM\n"

-type d        : search for folders
-iname '*pub*' : find the pattern case insensitive
%p             : display path of found folder
%TY            : time Year 
%Tm            : time month
%Td            : time day
%TH            : time hour
%TM            : time minutes
%TS            : time seconds
```

**For more information**
[Official webpage for GNU find](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html)
[25 Practical examples of the find command](https://www.librebyte.net/en/gnulinux/25-practical-examples-of-the-find-command/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slight variation, which makes use of `-regex` instead of `-names`:

```
find . -type d -regex ".*\($1\).*$" -printf 'The folder %P was modified on %Tb %Td %TH:%TM\n'
```

This can be either a single-line script or better yet - a function. Call it as so:

```
./finder.sh 'Vid\|Doc'
```

This makes for more idiomatic, `grep`-like approach.